# Receber HTML Table no Controller (SpringMVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, spring-mvc

Bom dia,

Possuo uma página onde o usuário digital 3 informações.

```
<input type="text" id="info01">
<input type="text" id="info01">
<input type="text" id="info01">
```

Ao digitar as 3, via javascript eu realizo um cálculo e crio uma tabela logo abaixo dinamicamente, com uma estrutura parecia com a de baixo.

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>Numero</td>
         <td>Valor</td>
         <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td><input type="text" value="10.00"></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="09/07/2015"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td><input type="text" value="15.00"></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="12/07/2015"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Como podem ver, existem duas colunas da tabela que são passíveis de alteração depois de geradas.

Meu problema é, como, na hora do submit da página, receber e quebrar essa tabela dentro do controller, para inserir no banco de dados.

Detalhes adicionais: Ao entrar na página, eu envio pela controller um objeto "lista", que é a lista de um obj com a mesma estrutura que a tabela recebe (Numero, Valor, Data)

Existe uma forma de eu popular esse objeto de sessão, via javascript ? Ou alguma forma de receber toda a tabela no Controller e fazer um loop na mesma ?
Não posso simplesmente na hora de gerar a tabela, atribuir os mesmos valores a um array e envia-lo para um hidden, pois caso o usuário altere os valores, os mesmo ficariam divergentes.

Comment: [Esse exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771218/how-to-get-a-table-from-an-html-page-using-java) mostra uma solução para o seu problema utilizando a biblioteca `JSoup`. Com essa biblioteca, é possível obter a table inteira no Java e iterar em seus elementos.

Comment: A unica forma de você enviar esses dados para o controller é submetendo um formulário? Teria como ser via Ajax? Via ajax eu posso apresentar uma solução pra isso. Aqui na empresa eu trabalho com SpringMVC também e já passei por algo parecido.

Comment: Acho que via ajax também daria certo onluiz, sendo assim enviaria os dados e retornaria um objeto java via ajax e demonstraria a lista a partir de um loop no objeto

Answer (score 0):

Salve!

Se for uma opção, eu sugiro você rever a sua funcionalidade para que ao invés de enviar a tabela criada de forma dinâmica inteira via formulário, manipular o DOM utilizando um framework para templates.

Você pode utilizar frameworks como KnockoutJS ou AngularJS.  Eles vão abstrair boa parte do seu trabalho em manipular elementos do seu HTML e interação com os *Controllers* via Ajax.

Esse exemplo utilizando o KnockoutJS é bem próximo do que você está pedindo:

### Template da tabela

```
<h2>Your seat reservations (<span data-bind="text: seats().length"></span>)</h2>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Passenger name</th><th>Meal</th><th>Surcharge</th><th></th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
            <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeSeat">Remove</a></td>
         </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addSeat, enable: seats().length < 5">Reserve another seat</button>

<h3 data-bind="visible: totalSurcharge() > 0">
    Total surcharge: $<span data-bind="text: totalSurcharge().toFixed(2)"></span>
</h3>
```

### Manipulação via KnockoutJS

```
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);

    self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function() {
        var price = self.meal().price;
        return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";        
    });    
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ReservationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    self.availableMeals = [
        { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
        { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
    ];    

    // Editable data
    self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
        new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
    ]);

    // Computed data
    self.totalSurcharge = ko.computed(function() {
       var total = 0;
       for (var i = 0; i < self.seats().length; i++)
           total += self.seats()[i].meal().price;
       return total;
    });    

    // Operations
    self.addSeat = function() {
        self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
    }
    self.removeSeat = function(seat) { self.seats.remove(seat) }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

A interação com servidor pode ser feita via Ajax utilizando jQuery:

```
// (...) suprimi o restante e recuperei o código abaixo de outro exemplo. substitua o "tasks" por "reservations" da listagem acima.
self.save = function() {
        $.ajax("/tasks", {
            data: ko.toJSON({ tasks: self.tasks }),
            type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(result) { alert(result) }
        });
    };

// Load initial state from server, convert it to Task instances, then populate self.tasks
$.getJSON("/tasks", function(allData) {
     var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function(item) { return new Task(item) });
    self.tasks(mappedTasks);
});
```

Os seus dados vão ser enviados para o servidor em uma forma estruturada e você poderá realizar a manipulação desses dados do jeito que lhe convier.

[Este outro artigo](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1304061) faz uma boa introdução ao KnockoutJS. Se você preferir também tem um [demo interativo](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro) (no qual o exemplo acima foi extraído).

*PS: Desculpe não colocar mais links para os frameworks citados, não tenho reputação o suficiente.*